# Is the cross product of two unit vectors itself a unit vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, cross-product

Or, in general, what does the magnitude of the cross product mean? How would you prove or disprove this?

Comment: Every time you come up with a question like this, the very very first thing you have to do is to consider examples. It is very easy to construct unit vectors, and when you have two of them, it is also very easy to compute the magnitude of their cross product. If you do this a few times, you will find the answer to your question at once.

Comment: The problem with "considering examples" is it doesn't give you the general rule. Fringe cases won't become evident. Looking it up in reference sources or asking experts is a more thorough approach.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

No - for example, the cross product of any unit vector with itself is 0. In general, the magnitude of the cross product of vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ is $$|\vec{a}\times\vec{b}|=|\vec{a}||\vec{b}|\sin(\theta)$$
where $\theta$ is the angle between the vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$. Thus, the cross product of two unit vectors $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ is itself a unit vector if and only if $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ are orthogonal, i.e. meet at right angles (this makes $\sin(\theta)=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})=1$).

As to the general interpretation of the magnitude of the cross product, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Geometric_meaning):

> The magnitude of the cross product can be interpreted as the positive area of the parallelogram having $a$ and $b$ as sides.

Answer (score 9):

$|\vec{a}\times\vec{b}|=|\vec{a}||\vec{b}||\sin(\theta)|$

Let $a,b$ unit vectors, so we have $|a| = |b| = 1$

$|\vec{a}\times\vec{b}|=|\sin(\theta)| \le 1$ (equality is when $|\sin(\theta)| = 1$ i.e. when a and b are perpendicular)

Therefore in general the result won't be a unit vector.

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the unit vectors you start with are perpendicular to each other (the dot product $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}$ is zero), then the cross product $\vec{a}\times\vec{b}$ will be a unit vector (a length of one).

If you don't have the above constraint for the input unit vectors, then the output of the cross product $\vec{a}\times\vec{b}$ is not guaranteed to be a unit vector, since the length depends on the angle (the length is $sin(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle between the input vectors).

This answer focuses on the special cases, for the generalizations see the other great answers.